# How can I display image behind div with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 rows in my container. In the second row I have 2 elements `one` and `two`. Now I am trying to display the image behind those too almost like a background. This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="someimageurl" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">one</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/RgrRQG)

Comment: hi please provide link

Comment: done thanks it is there

Comment: because the two div.col-md-6 are floating elements to add a background to those tags you need to wrap them in seperate div with a .clearfix

Answer (score 1):

Check if his works for you.

CSS:

```
.container{
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.contentBox {
  min-height: 300px
}
.imgBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  let: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.imgBox img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row contentBox">
    <div class="col-md-6">one</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox row">
    <img src="imageURL.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWejoP)

Comment: the one and two should be next to one another

Answer (score 0):

Is background-image what you're looking for?

HTML

```
<div id=RowDivWithBackground class=row>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.RowDivWithBackground {
    background-image: url('url/to/image');
    other-css-do-dads /*Probably some rgba action*/
}
```

Comment: Is this responsive too? It needs to cover the whole container.

Comment: I'm looking into your code pen link. You posted it just as I answered.

Ideally, it should be but you may need to do some CSS tweaking for it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the `img`-tag, try to use `position: fixed` and `z-index: -1` (or -2, -3, ...)

```css
.container {
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#imageAsBackground {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWTPbXeQy0Sy6xCbSwL_Vc4oQtMS-UNkUPOwRb3TxWHKKNlZ5Ycg" id="imageAsBackground" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">one</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you could use the image as a real background, try to use css for this then.

Like

```css
.container{
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.coolBackground {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWTPbXeQy0Sy6xCbSwL_Vc4oQtMS-UNkUPOwRb3TxWHKKNlZ5Ycg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row coolBackground">
    <div class="col-md-6">one</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`background-size: cover;` will adjust the image to the `width` of your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

use css to do that

```
#{your div ID}{
background-image: url("backgroundImage.png");  
}
```

i think this may be help you

Answer (score 0):

try this code

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium optio itaque quas ab facere, ipsa cumque consequatur nam id voluptatibus numquam, sapiente suscipit doloremque blanditiis non, ipsam sint vel molestias.</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.bg
{
  background-image:url(http://data.whicdn.com/images/12849966/large.jpg);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

hope it helps